# Python Scrapy ignoring Links and cutting of strings

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

My Scrapy Script doesn't do three important things:
- It doesn't save 3_ _ or 4_ _ Status Codes to my url_dictionary in my parse function. So I only can evaluate 200 html pages at the  moment

And:

- If I look for xpath "//h2" for example, my CSV file looks something like this:

  "https://seostrada.com"|"200"|"b'text/html'"|"[Mehr ...'>, PRODU...'>,
- First error: the headline gets cut off, as you can see here: "PRODU..."
- Second: I don't know how to remove this part in my output: `<Selector xpath='//h2' data=` 
  If I use //h2/text(), it still remains.

here is my crawler:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    # class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MySpidername"
    allowed_domains = allowed_subdomains
    start_urls = domains_to_crawl
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item', follow=True), ]

    # def parse(self, response):
    def parse_item(self, response):
        # self.logger.info('This is a new page called: %s', response.url)
        url_dictionary = {}
        url_dictionary["url"] = response.url
        url_dictionary["status"] = response.status
        url_dictionary["content-type"] = response.headers[b'Content-Type']
        for thing in objects_to_look_for:
            url_dictionary[thing] = response.xpath(thing)

        array_for_print.append(url_dictionary)
```

Comment: Please, ask a single question. Also, please make sure you check the documentation and other StackOverflow questions before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrapy shell https://seostrada.com/

In [1]: response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
Out[1]: []

In [2]: response.xpath("//h2/text()").extract()
Out[2]:
['Mehr Umsatz in Würzburg durch Suchmaschinen\xadoptimierung',
 'PRODUKTE ZUM VERLIEBEN',
 'Eins zu Eins - SEO Ausbildung',
 'Offpage Strategie',
 'SEO Webseite',
 'On-Page & On-Site Webentwicklung',
 'Integrale Projektbegleitung',
 'REFERENZEN',
 ' Unsere SEO Agentur ermöglichte folgende Top 10 Platzierungen',
 'Über mich – Der Würzburg SEO',
 'Wo ist SEO Strada für Online Marketing zu finden?',
 'Sind Sie wirklich sichtbar – im „World wide web“ ?',
 'Was macht ',
 ' in Würzburg anders?',
 ' ',
 'Falls Sie auf ',
 ' verzichten:',
 'Welche Garantien gibt es?']
```